# Assigning Macro to Text in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a vertical box list

[image]

, and every item has different hyperlink added to it

I have seen the way to assign macro to hyperlink by "Followhyperlink" and calling macro there, but in my case it's multiple hyperlinks and multiple Macros, not sure if that can be done.

Now, I need to add different macros to each hyperlink, is it possible?

Comment: What are those dark blue "things"? Are they buttons? shapes? what are they? Do you want to run a different macro for each hyperlink? Is that your question?

Comment: Why must they be hyperlinks? If they are shapes/buttons/etc/. can't you simply assign a macro to the shape itself? (hint: Yes, you can).

Comment: @mehow these are vertical box list i got from smartart option see the below link for image

http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMIHZ.jpg

Comment: Deleted my answer. Modifying it and reposting it :)

Comment: Well I can't add anything if Siddharth Rout is answering it, guaranteed to be awesome! (no pressure ;)  )

Comment: @RossC: You are way too kind :)

Comment: Not really @SiddharthRout you've saved me a lot of hassle in the last week or two, and it's much appreciated! I'm in a new job, writing VBA (which is not something I'm familiar with, nor am I a programmer!) and it's flying along! :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't assign macros to SmartArt by right clicking on them and clicking on "**Assign Macros**", what you can do is place a shape over each of them and format it so that it doesn't have a line or color. Once you do that then assign "**Assign Macros**" will be available to you. See this Screenshot. Also instead of adding text to the SmartArt, Add text to each Shape which has been placed on top of SmartArt.

[image]

and then this...

[image]

In that one macro, you can make use of `Application.Caller` and then retrieve the text of that shape. Based on the text, you can then perform a specific task. For Example

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = Sheet1.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    Select Case shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
        Case "Data Add on Y/N"
            '~~> Do Something
        Case "Product Data Last"
            '~~> Do Something

        '
        '~~> And So on
        '
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ fast and convenient

Comment: @David Zemens thanks for your response these box list is not giving me option to assign a Macro to it (For Screenshot see below link)

http://i.stack.imgur.com/cAbOu.jpg

Comment: @TusharVarshney: Updated my answer. BTW, I am not David ;)